# Why does bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT') switch to the Object Mode when executed?

Tags: python, scripting, edit-mode, blend-modes

I wrote a python script that modifies an existing blender armature that I have and some of these modifications include some commands that are only possible in Edit Mode. I know that depending on what is selected, some modes are not possible to switch to. In my case Pose, Edit and Object mode are the three available modes when I select my armature. In this instance, the following three commands could be used:

```
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='POSE')

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

Of the above three only the second one switches to wrong mode i.e. Object Mode. I  found no similar questions/forums on this kind of issue.
When trying to change to Edit Mode, blender changes to Object mode and my commands that are intended for edit mode show context error messages (as expected if in Pose/Object mode..) making it not possible for my script to apply the correct changes.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and how I could stop this from happening?? Thanks

Comment: Could we see your script, please? It might be faulty.

Comment: right in the beginning, when you try to switch to edit mode it does not work. When you select the armature, the menu bar with the modes shows Pose, Edit and Object Mode and the corresponding commands work except for the Edit mode one.. its the first like of my script...

Comment: I just experienced this today (in Blender 2.79). In my case, I set one armature to edit mode, deselected it, selected a different armature, then tried to set the different armature to edit mode -- this was where the `mode_set("EDIT")` silently failed. However, if I set the first armature back to object mode before selecting the other armature, then the `mode_set("EDIT")` on the other armature would succeed. I could be wrong, but Blender seems to only allow 1 armature to be in edit mode, and selecting a different armature (with bpy) doesn't automatically put the first back into object mode.

Comment: @TiberiumFusion you cannot select another armature while you are in *Edit Mode*. Basically this behavior is not possible as far as I know. There must be some perception mistake from the user. It would be good if you could show a gif or video demonstrating the "problem".

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I am not the OP so my circumstances are likely different. Here's a repro: https://blend-exchange.com/b/jJSZ2bvY for Blender 2.79 since you asked. It demonstrates the process of selecting a different armature while leaving the previous one in edit mode, as well as the side effects of this, which in turn demonstrates a disconnect between the behavior of the bpy interface what is really going on behind the scenes. This could easily be written off as improper use of bpy, but it makes no complaints and raises no exceptions when asked to do this "improper" thing.

Comment: @TiberiumFusion thanks for sharing. As far as I can see, we have version 3.6 now, where it's fixed, and we don't need 2.79 anymore.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I disagree. Blender 2.79 is still by far the superior choice in a few of my workflows, mainly interchange related, and my comments here will be useful information to other 2.79 users who may encounter the behavior noted by the OP.

Comment: Hello, @TiberiumFusion, I've taken the liberty of editing your last comment. By all means make your case, but we have to gauge _ad hominem_ phrasing carefully.. short-form exchanges between folks who don't yet know one another can easily be misread as offensive. Prefer a neutral tone, unless you're confident you'll be taken the right way. :)

Comment: @RobinBetts Hello. How is "we don't need 2.79 anymore :D" a neutral tone? Detracting a solution with a big smile... When one declares a legitimate solution is not needed - not merely personally disregarded by the commenter himself, but asserting that **we** do not need it, that ***everyone** has no need for it* (and with a wide grin, no less) - are you "confident you'll be taken the right way :)"? You rewrote my comment. Your logic compels you to rewrite Harry McKenzie's words as well. It is generally displeasing on forums to see people of popularity/power hold exemptions against the rules.

Comment: Hello, @TiberiumFusion, I take your point entirely. My edit was an attempt to resolve a complaint. Hence the asymmetry. Had _you_ made the complaint, the edit and my explanation of it would have been addressed to HarryMcKenzie. His original remark was made on what initially seems a reasonable assumption about newer versions.. your response validly argues the assumption is false. All of that is useful. I was just trying to strip out the bits which _had actually been read_ as personal attack. Now I'm better informed.  ( I'm pretty sure, in fact, neither of you intends to insult the other :). )

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie .. I've taken a similar liberty with your original comment.

Comment: @TiberiumFusion For me, lesson learned. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think I know what you are having here. if you see in the outliner, when you select an object via script it becomes orange and not yellow (if you have the default theme on) that means that the object is selected but not active. so if you go to edit mode, it goes automatically to the last object you edited, even if it's no longer selected. I recently faced the same and I solved it kinda the hard core way.

```
#set the objects to select
ob= bpy.data.objects.get("the_object_you_want_to_edit")
#deselect all the objects to avoid to edit all together
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
#select the desired object
ob.select_set(True)            
#set the desired object to active
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = ob
```

it's probably not an elegant solution but works 100% of the times , error free